# Why does Covid19 confirmed deaths lag behind all causes deaths?

Tags: lags, mortality, covid-19

It appears that Covid19 confirmed deaths dates lag about 10 days behind the all causes deaths.
This is at least true in European countries (I didn't check this elsewhere) and is particularly obvious at mortality peaks.

For example look at the following graphic, it is taken from [Euromomo](https://www.euromomo.eu/graphs-and-maps/) and shows in blue the weekly all cause mortality for a set of 23 European countries. And is overlaid with an orange graphic showing the weekly Covid19 confirmed deaths for the same set of countries*.
The lag is obvious :
[image: Euromomo all cause deaths (blue) vs Covid19 confirmed deaths (orange)]

What is the explanation for this lag ?
An obvious explanation would be that the dates of the Covid19 confirmed deaths are actually the dates of the deaths' reports, not the dates of the deaths.
I think this is the explanation, but I am not sure of this.

<sub>[*]: the orange graphic (Covid19 confirmed deaths) was made using data from https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/jhu/weekly_deaths.csv for 22 countries (Austria, Belgium, Cyprus, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Ireland, Israel, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Portugal, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, UK), **Italy was not included** because [it is covered only by 14%](https://www.euromomo.eu/how-it-works/background-data/) by Euromomo.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is due to report delays, as stated on https://ourworldindata.org/covid-deaths :

> The delay in reporting can be on the order of days and sometimes as long as a week. This means the number of deaths reported on a given day is not reflective of the actual number of deaths that occurred on that day.

Now, according to your graphic it would appear that in Europe the delays are not up to one week, but merely about 10 days in average.